# Loop multiple taxonomy in custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, tags

I have a custom post called "rock" and taxonomy "genres" i need to filter the posts with tag or something like

post_type > taxonomy > taxonomy_tag (tagsss)

I can not find a solution :(

i have register a new tag taxonomies in the fuctions (like tag) (is not whether it is a good choice)

```
    add_action( 'init', 'create_tag_taxonomiess', 0 );
    function create_tag_taxonomiess() 
    {
      // Add new taxonomy, NOT hierarchical (like tags)
      $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Tags' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Tags' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Tags' ),
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Tag' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Tag' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Tag' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tag Name' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate tags with commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove tags' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used tags' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Tags' ),
      ); 

      register_taxonomy('tagsss','rock',array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tag' ),
      ));

}
```

my loop in taxonomy-genres-events.php

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'rock','taxonomy' => 'genres','tagsss' =>'concerts', 'orderby' => 'menu-order' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $rock; ?>

 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

**EDIT:**

I have found the solution by myself

```
        <?php
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(

            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'taxonomy' => 'tagsss',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'concerts',

        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot natively query broadly by taxonomy, only by terms

If you study through [Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) in Codex it is now pretty easy to construct conditions for multiple sets of terms required.

Still it's not completely flexible, I won't know easy way to do things like “having any term in some taxonomy” on top of my head.